# Display results in a table form in view

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i am successfully fetching data from model named user_model to my controller named as **login_controller**. as shown below
in **user_model**:

```
function fetchData()
{
    $this->db->select('DeviceName, DeviceType,RegistrationDateTime,LastUpdateDateTime,LastPushNotificationSent');

    $query = $this->db->get('userinfo');
    $res=$query->result();
    if($res)
    {
        return $res;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

in my controller i have:

```
function displayDatabase()
{
    $data['tableInfo']=$this->user_model->fetchData();
    $this->load->view('adminPanel_view',$data);
}
```

where in adminPanel_view i am doing this:

```html
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-     width" id="sample_1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Serial No.</th>
    <th class="hidden-xs">Device Name</th>
    <th>Device Type</th>
    <th>RegistrationDateTime </th>
    <th>LastUpdateTime</th>
    <th>LastPushNotificationSent</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php //print_r ($tableInfo);exit;?>
<?php foreach($tableInfo  as $r): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php echo $r->DeviceName ?>

    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

but i am unable to show the data in table format. What am i doing wrong here.The data is displayed like this [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this in your view file...

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-full-     width" id="sample_1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Serial No.</th>
    <th class="hidden-xs">Device Name</th>
    <th>Device Type</th>
    <th>RegistrationDateTime </th>
    <th>LastUpdateTime</th>
    <th>LastPushNotificationSent</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php //print_r ($tableInfo);exit;?>
<?php foreach($tableInfo  as $r): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r->no ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->DeviceName ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->DeviceType ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->RegistrationDateTime ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->LastUpdateTime ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->LastPushNotificationSent ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->Actions ?></td>
    </tr>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You have to make the proper Table and set your result set proper.